# Can I somwhow manipulate the character displayed after the user edited an input field

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

Am I able to manipulate the input mechanism with simple event handlers? Imagine I have a simple textarea

```
<textarea id='t'></textarea>
```

Is there a way to change the value of the character which displayed after the user hitted a key?

```
document.getElementById('t').addEventListener("change", function(ev) {
  var ev = ev || window.event;
  // something like ev.return("X" + ev.key + "X") ?
});
```

So that always two X will surround the character at the actual caret position, no matter which key the user originally hit? I know, there is a `ev.preventDefault()` function, but this does just return **nothing**.

Every idea and every experience is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is still some stuff to polish, e.g. backspace or enter but you get the idea.

```js
document.getElementById('t').addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let textarea = document.getElementById('t');
  let cursorPos = textarea.selectionStart;

  let oldText = textarea.value;
  let insertText = 'x' + ev.key + 'x';
  let newText = [oldText.slice(0, cursorPos), insertText, oldText.slice(cursorPos)].join('');

  textarea.value = newText;
  
});
```

```html
<textarea id='t'></textarea>
```

Comment: Always a X was just an example. I am looking for a general solution.

Comment: So X is dynamic and might change while the user enters text?

Comment: More ore less. I want to insert x before and after the inputted text so that if I hit "c" i will get "xcx" at the current caret position

Comment: Alright, that clears things up. I'll update my answer shortly!

Answer (score 0):

Like this, which changes 'x' typed into in the input to 'y'...

```js
let el = document.getElementById('t');

function changed(value){
  if (value.includes('x')) {
    let newValue = value.replace("x","y")
    el.value = newValue;
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea type="text" id="t" onkeyup="changed(value)"></textarea>
```

Comment: Replacing the value seems great! But I need it for a huge text, so is iterating through such a mass of data really the only option? Without knowing the caret position I am not able to recognize at which position I have to change the text. Scanning the whole text would be the only option.